# java library to prepare user comments for displaying on the web?

Tags: java, blogs

Do you know of any good lightweight library in java to make good and safe HTML representation of user input? That's very generic task, I think. Consider: user leaves a comment in the blog - my task is to convert user comment into safe & nice HTML content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jsoup HTML [Cleaner](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html) with a configuration specified by a [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).

```
String unsafe = 
  "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
// now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```

Excerpt from the [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

Comment: This is safe - but not good.

Consider: user types "more info on www.abc.com/slkdflskdf" -> I want it to be rendered as link.

Comment: Oh, so you want a restricted safe-subset of html. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This seem to be exactly what's needed

Answer (score 0):

HTML Parser is a Java library used to parse HTML in either a linear or nested fashion. Primarily used for transformation or extraction, it features filters, visitors, custom tags and easy to use JavaBeans.

[HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

[Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

Comment: I'm aware of that library. But, it requires me to implement most of the stuff again.